# Disallow empty elements in XSD

Tags: java, validation, xsd, apache-axis

I've got a SOAP webservice built in Java with Axis2, and several elements in the request must not be empty. For e.g. strings I can validate the minimum length, but I also have date and boolean values that should not be empty. How can I validate this in the XSD?

An empty date element passes schema validation and gives me a null Date in the Java layer. I could check that it was not null, if not that one of my dates is optional and I have to return an error if the element is empty rather than treating it as if it was missing.

For optional elements, the Axis2 generated classes provide an 'isThisElementSpecified()' method, but where the element is mapped to an Object this returns false if the element is empty, so I can't distinguish between nulls due to empty and missing elements.

Empty boolean elements also pass schema validation and I get 'false' in the Java layer. Worse, although these elements are optional the isThisElementSpecified() methods return true for an empty element where it maps to a primitive, so I can't even treat them as if the elements weren't present (all but one must default to true if not specified).

All these elements are nillable="false" in the XSD. The booleans have a default value, but it has no effect (I read that 'default' only works on attribues).

I've found many answers about how to *accept* an empty date element, suggesting that normal behaviour is for it to fail schema validation as I want it to do, but it is not doing so here.

EDIT: An existing question about not allowing empty elements suggests a minLength=1 restriction, but that is not allowed for these datatypes.

The relevant bits of my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:tns="http://www.my.company.com/project" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.my.company.com/project" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="fooRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <!--snip some stuff-->
        <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:date" 
                    nillable="false" minOccurs="0" />
        <!--snip-->
        <xs:element name="includeBar" type="xs:boolean" 
                    default="true" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" />
        <!--snip-->
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @TomRedfern that question only mentions string elements and the answer suggested is to restrict the length to be at least 1 - as I mentioned, I am aware of that solution for strings. That type of restriction is not allowed on dates or booleans.

Comment: What validator accepts `<startDate/>` as valid against this schema?  Have you raised a bug report against it?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen On further investigation I learned that Axis2 doesn't validate against the schema unless you include a specific module which this webservice does not have. So... none.

The schema's only used to generate Java classes, and these include validation of explicit restrictions, but not in general of whether an element is empty.

The correct solution would have been to use the validation module, but due to circumstances outside my control that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted! It turns out that although minLength only applies to strings, the 'pattern' restriction can be used on any base type. `<xs:pattern value=".+" />` restricts the element to be non-empty.